# Some example of function in $L^{p_1}(\mathbb R)$ or $L^{p_2}(\mathbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to prove that $L^{p_1}(\mathbb R) \not\subset L^{p_2}(\mathbb R)$ and $L^{p_2}(\mathbb R) \not\subset L^{p_1}(\mathbb R)$ where $1\le p_1<p_2\le \infty$. Is there some example of function for these inclusions? Or should I follow a different way to prove it, I am a little confused.

Comment: Hint: Consider functions of the form $x \mapsto |x|^\alpha$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. For which parameters $\alpha$ is this function integrable in a neighborhood of $0$ and for which is it integrable 'near' $\pm \infty$?

Comment: @gerw for $\alpha >0$ this function integrable in a neighbothood of 0 and for $\alpha < 0$ near $\pm \infty$. So which $\alpha$ should I take for my task?

Comment: So it seems like if I take $f(x):=|x|^{m}\chi_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}+|x|^{-m}\chi_{(-\infty,-\epsilon)\cup(\epsilon,\infty)}$ where we take m such that $mp_2=p_1$ and $mp_1=\frac{1}{p_2}$ so this function lies in $L^{p_2}(\mathbb R)$ but not in $L^{p_1}(\mathbb R)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, the approach is correct. However, I think that you have to take two different $m$.